# Schedule a task every day using ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, calendar, background-thread, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` to run a particular task at `3 AM` in the morning everyday. Now I am not sure whether my below code will call `MyTask()` every `3 AM` in the morning? As I am not sure whether my logic is right or not

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Date aDate = ......// Current date or parsed date;
Calendar with = Calendar.getInstance();
with.setTime(aDate);
int hour = with.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int intDelayInHour = hour < 3 ? 3 - hour : 24 - (hour - 3);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), intDilayInHour, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

And to test this out, I need to wait for one day to see if it is working out and I don't want to do that.

Can anyone help me to identify whether my above code is right or not?

Comment: why don't change the time to the closer to your time to test? or Change the system time as well

Comment: I am able to run every 15 minutes but I am looking to run every 3 AM in the morning..

Answer (score 3):

Your code is also right but the problem is that the error window in you case is +-59 Minutes and +-59 seconds i.e. your tasks can be scheduled to run between 3.00 AM to 4.00 AM but if you want to more accurate then try this,

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Date aDate = new Date();// Current date or parsed date;

Calendar with = Calendar.getInstance();
with.setTime(aDate);
int hour = with.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int Minutes = with.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

int MinutesPassed12AM = hour * 60 + Minutes;
int MinutesAt3AM = 3 * 60;
int OneDayMinutes = 24 * 60;
long DelayInMinutes = MinutesPassed12AM <= MinutesAt3AM ? MinutesAt3AM - MinutesPassed12AM : OneDayMinutes - (MinutesPassed12AM - MinutesAt3AM);


scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), DelayInMinutes, OneDayMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

**EDIT**
If you look at the [Daylight saving time])http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) you can see in **how many countries** this daylight saving is used and in daylight saving the clocks are adjusted **maximum +-1 hour** and that too **only twice in a year**, and then too if your task is so robust that it should adjust to this change then you can adjust to this change by re-invoking the above mentioned code and shutdown previous scheduler by `scheduler.shutdown();`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and what about daylight savings issue?>

Comment: @SSH just see the edited answer for your daylight savings issue.